# Laravel Route Parameters change public_path

Tags: php, laravel

```
    #1 public/    
    Route::get('/foo', function(){ return view('foo'); });

    #2(this change all public_path to public/bar/)
    Route::get('/bar/{id}', 'BarController@bar'); 

    its nice and clean in my blade        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <img src="images/foo.jpg">
```

I have a problem when I add route parameter, it change my public_path in blade

I don't want to add `public_path()` in my blade which is not nice and clean, anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: use src="{{url('images/foo.jpg')}}" for img also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either add `/` to the beginning  of the `src` or use `url()` (or `asset()`).

```
src="/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
```

or

```
src="{{ url('vendor/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') }}"
```

Just FYI, you wouldn't use `public_path` as it would give you the fully qualified path in your file system not a url.

Hope this helps!

Comment: add / is nice, but I will need to set my root to public (i was working in localhost now, which is annoy)